# In India is the Judiciary empowered to make reasonable exceptions to a law in a trial?

Tags: india

In case a statute is clearly of General application or doesn't allow affirmative defences, is it still possible for the Judiciary to interpret the law in a way to accommodate exceptional cases ? or would this be against the principles of public policy and their role ?

For example for crimes against women, children and underclasses the law seems to be interpreted very broadly.

Comment: This is really asking at too broad of a level of generality. Sometimes a court can, and sometimes it can't, and it deeply depends upon what the law in question is and what the circumstance is.

Answer (score 2):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Absolutely not.  This would be contrary to the principle of the supremacy of parliament.  If it's written in the statute, that's what the law says.

*However* judges do show some flexibility in interpreting the wording of laws.  Furthermore, in the case of crimes, they are also (usually) able to pass a sentence of an "absolute discharge" which means no fine, or prison, or risk of further punishment (but still a criminal record).

Note that it is usually for a crime to have a "without lawful excuse" or similar clause, so the question doesn't arise.

Comment: I do recall some judgements along the lines of "This may not be what Parliament *intended,* but it's what they *enacted,* so we will follow the law." That should cut both ways.